# Cropping a Video Panorama

Tags: video, 360video

**Summary**: How do I get VideoStitch Studio, AutoPano Video, or any other video stitcher to properly crop an equirectangular or cylindrical projection?

**Details**: I am creating a wide-angle video from two GoPro (120° HFoV each) overlapped by about 50%. The desired end result is about 190° horizontal, 45° vertical. When I bring two (synchronized) video frames into [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) as pictures, I can set up a stitch and projection and crop…

[image: Two warped images with crop markers]
<sup>*(Ignore the phantom hand and unblended screenshot)*</sup>

…and Hugin produces the result I want:
[image]

However, when I bring the two videos into either [VideoStitch Studio](http://www.video-stitch.com/studio/) or [AutoPano Video](http://www.kolor.com/autopano-video/) I can get the two videos synchronized and calibrated, but I cannot figure out how to crop the projection to include the region of interest. (With VideoStitch Studio I even load the Hugin `.pto` file; I thought this should include the crop.) The videos they produce are always a small region of the video inside a sea of black:
[image]

Using either of these two video-stitchers—or any other process—how can I get Hugin-like cropping of my videos?

(The final video dimensions will be very high resolution, on the order of 6k horizontal pixels, so I'd strongly prefer not to say *"Just render it extra extra big and then use After Effects to crop out the center."*)

Comment: I do know that there are several stitching artifacts, both in the "result I want" image and the screenshot of the video. At this point I'm trying to figure out the proper production pipeline—which software to buy—and so I'm not yet spending a lot of time getting really good control points set up in any package.

Comment: Getting closer: in AutoPano Video I can open the Preview pane, click on the tiny "Authoring" tab in the Timeline pane, and then the projection mode can be changed and I can drag and zoom the view. I still can't set an arbitrary aspect ratio, nor crop asymmetrically around the 'horizon'.

Comment: Support from VideoStitch Studio wrote: _"Right you will only be able to create a full sphere is Studio in an equirectangular projection (no zoom, no crop) but it will enable you to bypass the template options.
In my opinion, stitching 2 videos might not be the best option for what you are trying to do as they will be stitched in a full sphere (using a wider lens on your camera might be better)."_ So: VideoStitch Studio cannot produce the output.